# The Hapijs Glue 'compose' function should not work, but it does. How?

Tags: javascript, hapi.js

Can anyone explain to me how this could ever work? I see a function with one argument, and it seems to throw an error whenever it has "less than or equal to 3" arguments, which would be always.

```
  exports.compose = function (manifest /*, [options], [callback] */) {

  Hoek.assert(arguments.length <= 3, 'Invalid number of arguments');
```

I see this here:

https://github.com/hapijs/glue/blob/67f8331326e11fb91c1ee0c4a99ac6c0ec310f5e/lib/index.js#L38

How does this work? Am I misreading it?

Comment: It will throw an error if `!(arguments.length <= 3)`.

Answer (score 0):

In JS, declaring

```
var f = function (a, b, c) {
  console.log(a+b+c);
};
```

is equivalent to

```
var f = function () {
  var a = arguments[0];
  var b = arguments[1];
  var c = arguments[2];
  console.log(a+b+c);
};
```

This means parameters you name are just a "nickname" for `arguments[i]`, and that you can call a function with or without parameters: the "expected" (named) parameters will simply be `undefined`.

Contrary to other languages, a function's parameters are not part of its signature. This makes coding less strict, as you can make a wrong call that would be executed without interpreter error. However, this is coherent with the weak typing nature of JS: function are also kind of loosely typed, as their signature is just their name.

All functions being *de facto* [variadic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) that way, it inherently allows the principles of [overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading), since your function may behave differently depending on the amount and nature of arguments. (PHP, which is loosely typed too, has the same mechanism.)

See [the arguments object definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) which will tell you more about this feature!